# TeamCity / TestFlight API Upload Error

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, testflight

I am trying to integrate the TestFlighApp.com API with my TeamCity continuous integration environment. However, after the .ipa is generated and I get to the following step:

```
  curl http://testflightapp.com/api/builds.json \
    --form file=@%teamcity.build.checkoutDir%/application.ipa \
    --form api_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \
    --form team_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \
    --form notes='Built from TeamCity. %env.TEAMCITY_BUILDCONF_NAME%'  \
    --form notify=True  \
    --form distribution_lists='API'
```

I get the following results:

```
Step 3/4: Distribute to TestFlight (Command Line) (1m)
Starting: /Applications/buildAgent/temp/agentTmp/custom_script2782333615207409098
in directory: /Applications/buildAgent/work/7a1d432fea96afc0
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
 89   985    0     0   89   883      0    759  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--   815
 89   985    0     0   89   883      0    408  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:--   423
 89   985    0     0   89   883      0    279  0:00:03  0:00:03 --:--:--   286
 89   985    0     0   89   883      0    211  0:00:04  0:00:04 --:--:--   216
 89   985    0     0   89   883      0    170  0:00:05  0:00:05 --:--:--   173
 89   985    0     0   89   883      0    143  0:00:06  0:00:06 --:--:--     0
 89   985    0     0   89   883      0    123  0:00:08  0:00:07  0:00:01     0
 89   985    0     0   89   883      0    108  0:00:09  0:00:08  0:00:01     0
 89   985    0     0   89   883      0     96  0:00:10  0:00:09  0:00:01     0
 89   985    0     0   89   883      0     86  0:00:11  0:00:10  0:00:01     0
 89   985    0     0   89   883      0     79  0:00:12  0:00:11  0:00:01     0
 89   985    0     0   89   883      0     72  0:00:13  0:00:12  0:00:01     0
 89   985    0     0   89   883      0     67  0:00:14  0:00:13  0:00:01     0
 89   985    0     0   89   883      0     62  0:00:15  0:00:14  0:00:01     0
 89   985    0     0   89   883      0     58  0:00:16  0:00:15  0:00:01     0
 89   985    0     0   89   883      0     54  0:00:18  0:00:16  0:00:02     0
 89   985    0     0   89   883      0     51  0:00:19  0:00:17  0:00:02     0
 89   985    0     0   89   883      0     48  0:00:20  0:00:18  0:00:02     0
 89   985    0     0   89   883      0     46  0:00:21  0:00:19  0:00:02     0
 89   985    0     0   89   883      0     43  0:00:22  0:00:20  0:00:02     0
 89   985    0     0   89   883      0     41  0:00:24  0:00:21  0:00:03     0
 89   985    0     0   89   883      0     39  0:00:25  0:00:22  0:00:03     0
 89   985    0     0   89   883      0     38  0:00:25  0:00:23  0:00:02     0
 89   985    0     0   89   883      0     36  0:00:27  0:00:24  0:00:03     0
 89   985    0     0   89   883      0     35  0:00:28  0:00:25  0:00:03     0
 89   985    0     0   89   883      0     33  0:00:29  0:00:26  0:00:03     0
 89   985    0     0   89   883      0     32  0:00:30  0:00:27  0:00:03     0
 89   985    0     0   89   883      0     31  0:00:31  0:00:28  0:00:03     0
 89   985    0     0   89   883      0     30  0:00:32  0:00:29  0:00:03     0
 89   985    0     0   89   883      0     29  0:00:33  0:00:30  0:00:03     0
 89   985    0     0   89   883      0     28  0:00:35  0:00:31  0:00:04     0
 89   985    0     0   89   883      0     27  0:00:36  0:00:32  0:00:04     0
 89   985    0     0   89   883      0     26  0:00:37  0:00:33  0:00:04     0
 89   985    0     0   89   883      0     25  0:00:39  0:00:34  0:00:05     0
 89   985    0     0   89   883      0     25  0:00:39  0:00:35  0:00:04     0
 89   985    0     0   89   883      0     24  0:00:41  0:00:36  0:00:05     0
 89   985    0     0   89   883      0     23  0:00:42  0:00:37  0:00:05     0
 89   985    0     0   89   883      0     23  0:00:42  0:00:38  0:00:04     0
 89   985    0     0   89   883      0     22  0:00:44  0:00:39  0:00:05     0
 89   985    0     0   89   883      0     21  0:00:46  0:00:40  0:00:06     0
 89   985    0     0   89   883      0     21  0:00:46  0:00:41  0:00:05     0
 89   985    0     0   89   883      0     20  0:00:49  0:00:42  0:00:07     0
 89   985    0     0   89   883      0     20  0:00:49  0:00:43  0:00:06     0
 89   985    0     0   89   883      0     19  0:00:51  0:00:44  0:00:07     0
 89   985    0     0   89   883      0     19  0:00:51  0:00:45  0:00:06     0
 89   985    0     0   89   883      0     19  0:00:51  0:00:46  0:00:05     0
 89   985    0     0   89   883      0     18  0:00:54  0:00:47  0:00:07     0
 89   985    0     0   89   883      0     18  0:00:54  0:00:48  0:00:06     0
 89   985    0     0   89   883      0     17  0:00:57  0:00:49  0:00:08     0
 89   985    0     0   89   883      0     17  0:00:57  0:00:50  0:00:07     0
 89   985    0     0   89   883      0     17  0:00:57  0:00:51  0:00:06     0
 89   985    0     0   89   883      0     16  0:01:01  0:00:52  0:00:09     0
 89   985    0     0   89   883      0     16  0:01:01  0:00:53  0:00:08     0
 89   985    0     0   89   883      0     16  0:01:01  0:00:54  0:00:07     0
 89   985    0     0   89   883      0     15  0:01:05  0:00:55  0:00:10     0
 89   985    0     0   89   883      0     15  0:01:05  0:00:56  0:00:09     0
 89   985    0     0   89   883      0     15  0:01:05  0:00:57  0:00:08     0
 89   985    0     0   89   883      0     15  0:01:05  0:00:58  0:00:07     0
 89   985    0     0   89   883      0     14  0:01:10  0:00:59  0:00:11     0
 89   985    0     0   89   883      0     14  0:01:10  0:01:00  0:00:10     0
 89   985    0     0   89   883      0     14  0:01:10  0:01:00  0:00:10     0
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
Process exited with code 52
Step Distribute to TestFlight (Command Line) failed
```

Any assistance with this would be GREATLY appreciated!

Thanks
Ryan

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't see your full comment. Can you please repost?

Comment: What is the response of follow command on TeamCity server? `curl http://testflightapp.com/api/builds.json -v`

Comment: curl http://testflightapp.com/api/builds.json -v
 About to connect() to testflightapp.com port 80 (#0)
   Trying 110.173.143.147...
 connected
 Connected to testflightapp.com (110.173.143.147) port 80 (#0)
 GET /api/builds.json HTTP/1.1
 User-Agent: curl/7.24.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin12.0) libcurl/7.24.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8r zlib/1.2.5
 Host: testflightapp.com
 Accept: */*
 
 HTTP/1.1 405 METHOD NOT ALLOWED
 Server: nginx
 Date: Wed, 06 Feb 2013 07:18:12 GMT
 Transfer-Encoding: chunked
 
 Connection #0 to host testflightapp.com left intact
 Closing connection #0. I'm not sure this will help.

Comment: It seems ok. What is the size of your upload file?

Comment: It is 109MB, plenty below the 800MB max. Oh, so close but so far away!

Comment: - Is your CI server configured to use a proxy ? If so try without the proxy

- Is your CI server running in a resource constrained environment (e.g. in the cloud)

Try running the command with extra verbosity arguments.

E.g.

curl -v -v -v --keepalive-time 10 ...

(that might not help, it depends on your OS)